# “That’s a wake-up call that investors are really worried,” Boodry said, overriding Son’s previous reticence to slim the portfolio

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

“That’s a wake-up call that investors are really worried,” Boodry said, **overriding Son’s previous reticence** to slim the portfolio.

what does (overriding) means in this sentence?

Comment: I'll mention in passing that *reticence*, which properly means unwillingness to speak (it's related to *tacit*), would be better replaced here with *reluctance*.

Answer (score 2):

I read the article that quote came from, and I think the structure of the sentence isn't quite correct.
"Son" is the CEO of the company Softbank. He was previously reluctant to sell assets to raise cash and reduce debt.
"Boodry" is an analyst working for a company that watches Softbank. He has said that Softbank's "conglomerate discount" has increased, and that "that is a wake-up call that investors are really worried".
I believe the intended meaning of the quoted sentence is:

*The analyst believes that the news about the "conglomerate discount" has overridden the CEO's reluctance to sell assets.*

The way it's phrased in the sentence you quoted, it sounds as if Boodry is overriding something, but that doesn't make sense.

If your question was just about the meaning of "override", it's approximately "prevail over".
See [M-W "override" (3)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/override)

Answer (score 2):

Jack is correct, but this builds on Jack's answer.

The sentence in question was reported in a [Reuters article](https://www.fidelity.com/news/article/top-news/202003230107RTRSNEWSCOMBINED_KBN21A0F2-OUSBS_1). My read of the context is this:

1. Softbank is an investment bank. So, it owns various assets, like its infamous stake in WeWork. The short version is that WeWork is in some financial distress due to management. The long version is truly a sordid tale that you are better off Googling.
2. Their CEO had previously been reluctant to sell its assets (this is the reference to "slim the porfolio" in the original quote.
3. Their CEO went back on his decision. He is planning to sell about US$41 billion of assets, and to use the proceeds to buy back shares. This move basically benefits its shareholders (corporations wishing to do this might also declare dividends, which are regular payments; e.g. Softbank might declare a dividend of ¥100 a quarter). Shareholders had previously been nervous about Softbank, in large part due to WeWork.

"Override" can definitely mean something like "to prevail over", as given in the [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/override). However, in this context, I believe the more correct meaning is "to set aside; annul". Here, the CEO overrode his own previous decision due to pressure from shareholders (and yes, investing in WeWork was a blunder, but that's off topic).

Some alternative phrases:

- "the CEO *reversed* his previous decision not to sell assets"
- "market pressure *overcame* his previous reluctance to sell assets"

This sentence doesn't quite match the structure of the quote. However, say the CEO had given some sort of order to do something. They could *rescind* a previous order. In the legal setting, a court can *vacate* a previous court order.

CEO stands for Chief Executive Officer, so there is nobody to override him in the sense of prevailing over him or reversing a decision. In theory, CEOs answer to a board of directors, and I don't believe that they would override operational decisions, but they could fire the CEO. If it were the Chief Financial Officer (CFO, a position subordinate to the CEO) who made some decision, the CEO could override the CFO. In this context, you might also say *overrule* or *annul*.

Bonus:
In nautical settings only (e.g. navy, merchant marine, coast guard, marine infantry), to [belay an order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60866/is-it-proper-to-ask-to-belay-a-request-to-a-superior/118161) means to cancel the previous order. Belay has some alternative meanings (e.g. "belay that" = "stop that") as discussed on that SE link.